# JQuery- Can't select an option in select element?

Tags: jquery, select, input

```
<select id="size" name="size"><option value="3944330">Medium</option>
<option value="3944331">Large</option>
<option value="3944332">XLarge</option></select>
```

I'm trying to select the large and XLarge size but it's not working, here is the code I put:

```
$("input[value='size']").filter(function(i, e) { return $(e).text() == "Large"})
```

I'm trying to select the button by not using the value (3944331) but the name (Large).

Comment: Try answer i posted and check if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

Here are the list of issues in your code:

1)  You have used wrong selector for select element. You should use `select` instead of `input`.

2)  use attribute `name` instead of `value`. as size is value of name attribute

3)  also you need to filter from option element.hence modify selector to target options in select element

```
$("select[name='size'] option").filter(function(i, e) { return $(e).text() == "Large"})
```

NOTE: If you are looking for selecting the above option element then add property selected as true

```
   $("select[name='size'] option").filter(function(i, e) { 
         return $(e).text() == "Large"
   }).prop("selected", true)
```

Comment: Also use name instead of the value attribute

Answer (score 0):

The `input[value='size']` selector search for input element with attribute `value="size"` so update it with `id` selector or select based on name.

Use [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo-class selector to select element which cotains specific text.

```
$("#size option:contains('Large')")
```

---

Or [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method for exact text match where `this` can be used to refer the element.

```
$("#size option").filter(function(){
  $(this).text() == 'Large';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#mySelect1").find("option[text=" + text1 + "]").attr("selected", true).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. Select an option by value :

   ```
    // click will auto set selected attribute
    $('select#size option[value="Large"]').click();
   ```
2. Select an option by text :

   ```
    // click will auto set selected attribute
    $('select#size option:contains("Large")').click();
   ```